# How can I call the name of a user if the mail is from esuario from parse server in Android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

In summary, if the mail is registered, how can I show the name of that user from Android with parse server.
Help please, this is for a college project.

In this function it already tells me that the email is registered, but I need to know the user of that email and show it in a TextView or with a log.d().

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("init_app");
                                            query.whereEqualTo("email", userdialog.getText().toString());
                                            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
                                            {
                                                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)
                                                {
                                                    if (object == null)
                                                    {
                                                        Toast.makeText(initapp.this,"Are not you a registered user",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        return;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                      
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a query, for user search  match with this email,in your callback this object 'object' represent this user,and now you:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("init_app");
query.whereEqualTo("email", userdialog.getText().toString());                                            
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>(){
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e){
        if (object == null || e!=null){
            Toast.makeText(initapp.this,"Are not you a registered user",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }else{//and here 
            //you can get args in this object

            //object.get("name");
            //object.get("age");
            //whatever 
            //and
            textView.setText(object.get("name"))
        }                                     
    }
```

});